# Include a nested element in Django Rest framework serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to list all the images of a single Item in Django rest Framework serializer.

In models :

```
class Item(TimeStampedModel, AbsoluteUrlMixin, ObjectReviewsMixin):
   ...

class ItemImage(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='pictures')
    picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="items")
```

in the viewset :

```
class ItemImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ItemImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer()
```

in serializer :

```
class ItemImageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemImage
        fields =(
            'picture'
        )


class ItemSerializer(ObjectReviewsSerializer):
    pictures = ItemImageSerializer()
    ...
```

When I got to `/items/1` I have empty response for the field pictures
Like `"pictures":{}` While it should return the list of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including the `pictures` field on the `ImageSerializer`, but you are not telling Django REST framework that it can accept multiple values.

You should pass `many=True` into the field when initializing it

```
class ItemImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemImage
        fields =(
            'picture',
        )


class ItemSerializer(ObjectReviewsSerializer):
    pictures = ItemImageSerializer(many=True)
    ...
```

And the reason why it wasn't triggering an error is because you were missing the comma after `'picture'` in the tuple. It is highly recommended to always include the trailing comma, otherwise single-value tuples will be split up. So your fields were really `('p', 'i', 'c', 't', 'u', 'r', 'e', )` which is obviously not what you want.

The other reason is because you were using `Serializer` like a `ModelSerializer`, so no fields were actually being generated in the first place. Django REST framework will ignore any fields included in `Meta.fields` which are not actually defined, which is why you were always getting a blank object.

I've included the comma in the modified code, as well as changing your serializer to a `ModelSerializer`.

Comment: it gives the correct number but still empty : `pictures":[{},{},{}]`

Comment: @Sekai Just edited it to include the missing comma in your `fields` tuple.

Comment: Same response. I would like you if possible to confirm with me the viewset and if I'm doing it right.

Comment: @Sekai Found the other issue, at this point it should start triggering exceptions if there is any other issues that we've missed.

Comment: Awesome ! Now it works ! 
Please tell me, does this also work at writing ? I mean when I send pictures from my app. or should I add something to my serializer ?

Comment: It _should_, though you are going to [have to define how writing works](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) on your own.